# How to fix a bad PSD fit using scipy.optimize.curvefit

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a power spectral density with a single peak that I am trying to fit using a custom function (simple harmonic oscillator). I am feeding in initial parameters that appear to be reasonably close based on plotting them with the raw data however the curve_fit function fails to fit the data reasonably.

This is using python 3.7 on a Windows 10 computer. I have tried simplifying to a minimal dataset in order to troubleshoot the problem but can't seem to figure it out.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def SHO(f,f0,a,b,Q):
    power_app = (a*(f0**4))/((f**2-f0**2)**2 + (f*f0/Q)**2)+b
    return power_app

x = np.array([20015.69858713, 20054.94505495, 20094.19152276, 20133.43799058,
       20172.6844584 , 20211.93092622, 20251.17739403, 20290.42386185,
       20329.67032967, 20368.91679749, 20408.16326531, 20447.40973312,
       20486.65620094, 20525.90266876, 20565.14913658, 20604.3956044 ,
       20643.64207221, 20682.88854003, 20722.13500785, 20761.38147567,
       20800.62794349, 20839.8744113 , 20879.12087912, 20918.36734694,
       20957.61381476, 20996.86028257, 21036.10675039, 21075.35321821,
       21114.59968603, 21153.84615385, 21193.09262166, 21232.33908948,
       21271.5855573 , 21310.83202512, 21350.07849294, 21389.32496075,
       21428.57142857, 21467.81789639, 21507.06436421, 21546.31083203,
       21585.55729984, 21624.80376766, 21664.05023548, 21703.2967033 ,
       21742.54317111, 21781.78963893, 21821.03610675, 21860.28257457,
       21899.52904239, 21938.7755102 , 21978.02197802, 22017.26844584,
       22056.51491366, 22095.76138148, 22135.00784929, 22174.25431711,
       22213.50078493, 22252.74725275, 22291.99372057, 22331.24018838,
       22370.4866562 , 22409.73312402, 22448.97959184, 22488.22605965,
       22527.47252747, 22566.71899529, 22605.96546311, 22645.21193093,
       22684.45839874, 22723.70486656, 22762.95133438, 22802.1978022 ,
       22841.44427002, 22880.69073783, 22919.93720565, 22959.18367347,
       22998.43014129])
y = np.array([5.65544381e-18, 5.45458563e-18, 4.89893664e-18, 4.91109125e-18,
       4.93294827e-18, 5.05712667e-18, 4.60680439e-18, 4.93761900e-18,
       5.25185317e-18, 5.71913103e-18, 5.88133465e-18, 5.51506519e-18,
       5.28196380e-18, 5.37739619e-18, 7.11067243e-18, 7.38655966e-18,
       5.79091461e-18, 6.70951199e-18, 7.21589026e-18, 8.57034517e-18,
       1.03078084e-17, 8.62319615e-18, 8.85873439e-18, 9.51253497e-18,
       8.56661324e-18, 7.84093758e-18, 7.91955750e-18, 8.11798984e-18,
       7.45548785e-18, 8.99928113e-18, 1.11020034e-17, 1.39963873e-17,
       1.34092392e-17, 1.60334619e-17, 1.55794254e-17, 1.20782547e-17,
       1.52164359e-17, 1.86563455e-17, 2.09536229e-17, 2.47011325e-17,
       2.64443357e-17, 3.23877863e-17, 3.82919169e-17, 4.36682960e-17,
       4.18201004e-17, 6.53800912e-17, 9.40340341e-17, 1.20969462e-16,
       1.75570644e-16, 2.59463564e-16, 3.83125755e-16, 5.63178280e-16,
       6.19699349e-16, 5.95325659e-16, 4.71509035e-16, 3.39690667e-16,
       1.90432901e-16, 2.05109520e-16, 2.71918806e-16, 2.42928468e-16,
       1.33335030e-16, 7.93620990e-17, 5.58089972e-17, 3.71690525e-17,
       4.72718831e-17, 3.73266547e-17, 2.06817670e-17, 2.01518733e-17,
       2.40691290e-17, 1.76559440e-17, 1.88179105e-17, 2.23351216e-17,
       2.33958117e-17, 1.87067097e-17, 1.59996492e-17, 1.02671264e-17,
       1.21233722e-17])

p_guess = [22000,10e-19,10e-18,20]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(SHO, x, y, 
                               p0 = p_guess, 
                               bounds = ((0,0,0,0),(np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf)))
plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.plot(x,SHO(x,*p_guess),'r-')
#plt.plot(x,SHO(x,*popt),'g-')
plt.show()
```

I have commented out the line produced by the final parameter estimates but you can see in the plot that the initial guess is relatively close.

If you uncomment the line then it is clear that the final fit is far worse than even the initial guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example code that appears to give a good fit, using scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm to create initial parameter estimates. That module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, requiring bounds within which to search. I used data max and min values for most bounds, and for the bounds on Q I used -10 and +10 to bracket your p0 value. Ranges for the initial parameter values are much easier to determine than specific values.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([20015.69858713, 20054.94505495, 20094.19152276, 20133.43799058,
       20172.6844584 , 20211.93092622, 20251.17739403, 20290.42386185,
       20329.67032967, 20368.91679749, 20408.16326531, 20447.40973312,
       20486.65620094, 20525.90266876, 20565.14913658, 20604.3956044 ,
       20643.64207221, 20682.88854003, 20722.13500785, 20761.38147567,
       20800.62794349, 20839.8744113 , 20879.12087912, 20918.36734694,
       20957.61381476, 20996.86028257, 21036.10675039, 21075.35321821,
       21114.59968603, 21153.84615385, 21193.09262166, 21232.33908948,
       21271.5855573 , 21310.83202512, 21350.07849294, 21389.32496075,
       21428.57142857, 21467.81789639, 21507.06436421, 21546.31083203,
       21585.55729984, 21624.80376766, 21664.05023548, 21703.2967033 ,
       21742.54317111, 21781.78963893, 21821.03610675, 21860.28257457,
       21899.52904239, 21938.7755102 , 21978.02197802, 22017.26844584,
       22056.51491366, 22095.76138148, 22135.00784929, 22174.25431711,
       22213.50078493, 22252.74725275, 22291.99372057, 22331.24018838,
       22370.4866562 , 22409.73312402, 22448.97959184, 22488.22605965,
       22527.47252747, 22566.71899529, 22605.96546311, 22645.21193093,
       22684.45839874, 22723.70486656, 22762.95133438, 22802.1978022 ,
       22841.44427002, 22880.69073783, 22919.93720565, 22959.18367347,
       22998.43014129])
yData = numpy.array([5.65544381e-18, 5.45458563e-18, 4.89893664e-18, 4.91109125e-18,
       4.93294827e-18, 5.05712667e-18, 4.60680439e-18, 4.93761900e-18,
       5.25185317e-18, 5.71913103e-18, 5.88133465e-18, 5.51506519e-18,
       5.28196380e-18, 5.37739619e-18, 7.11067243e-18, 7.38655966e-18,
       5.79091461e-18, 6.70951199e-18, 7.21589026e-18, 8.57034517e-18,
       1.03078084e-17, 8.62319615e-18, 8.85873439e-18, 9.51253497e-18,
       8.56661324e-18, 7.84093758e-18, 7.91955750e-18, 8.11798984e-18,
       7.45548785e-18, 8.99928113e-18, 1.11020034e-17, 1.39963873e-17,
       1.34092392e-17, 1.60334619e-17, 1.55794254e-17, 1.20782547e-17,
       1.52164359e-17, 1.86563455e-17, 2.09536229e-17, 2.47011325e-17,
       2.64443357e-17, 3.23877863e-17, 3.82919169e-17, 4.36682960e-17,
       4.18201004e-17, 6.53800912e-17, 9.40340341e-17, 1.20969462e-16,
       1.75570644e-16, 2.59463564e-16, 3.83125755e-16, 5.63178280e-16,
       6.19699349e-16, 5.95325659e-16, 4.71509035e-16, 3.39690667e-16,
       1.90432901e-16, 2.05109520e-16, 2.71918806e-16, 2.42928468e-16,
       1.33335030e-16, 7.93620990e-17, 5.58089972e-17, 3.71690525e-17,
       4.72718831e-17, 3.73266547e-17, 2.06817670e-17, 2.01518733e-17,
       2.40691290e-17, 1.76559440e-17, 1.88179105e-17, 2.23351216e-17,
       2.33958117e-17, 1.87067097e-17, 1.59996492e-17, 1.02671264e-17,
       1.21233722e-17])


def func(f,f0,a,b,Q):
    power_app = (a*(f0**4))/((f**2-f0**2)**2 + (f*f0/Q)**2)+b
    return power_app


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([min(xData), max(xData)]) # search bounds forf0
    parameterBounds.append([min(yData), max(yData)]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([min(yData), max(yData)]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([10.0, 30.0]) # search bounds for Q

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: I do like this implementation as a semi-automated method to generate parameter estimates. I did however find that it sometimes fails to fit the data as well but this can usually be solved by selecting more or less of the shoulders around the peak of interest. I wonder if this has something to do with the step size that curve_fit uses when exploring parameter space relative to the extremely small numbers I am working with?

Comment: If you were to choose search parameter ranges of +/- infinity, this method would not be useful. I guessed at some search ranges for my example, being unfamiliar with the specifics of the problem, and my guesses appeared to work. The search ranges can be generous, but if they do not bracket what should be good initial parameter estimates then such estimates are unlikely to be found. If you can infer good search ranges - ranges, mind you - by knowing the equation and data (with scatterplot review)  this method almost always seems to work well in my experience.